# Derive an inequality using Summation by Parts

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can someone help me to derive the following inequality using Summation by Parts?

$a_n$ is a decreasing sequence of positive terms. 
$$\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+p} a_k \sin kx\right| \le \frac{2a_{m+1}}{\sin (x/2)}$$ 
where $x=\pi /m$, $x \in [\pi/(n+p),\pi]$, and also $na_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. I'm really stuck and have no idea how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: You really need to say more about $a_n$.  The left side depends on the relative sizes of $a_{m+1}, a_{m+2}, \ldots, a_{n+p}$.  There's no way the right hand side can bound that when it only depends on the first coefficient.

Comment: Also, do you mean $x = \pi/m$?  Of course it's arithmetically equivalent to $m = \pi/x$, but the latter is a very confusing way to describe this relation since $m$ has to be an integer but $x$ would otherwise be an unconstrained real parameter.

Comment: Sorry I've added some additional information to the problem about $a_n$

Comment: And yes, I meant $x=\pi/m$

Answer (score 1):

In order to use summation by parts, we first need to write the left hand side in the form
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+p} a_k (b_{k+1} - b_k).$$
We can achieve this by computing the following multiple of sines
$$-2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sin(kx)
=\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}+kx\right)
-\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}+kx\right)
=\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}(2k+1)\right)
-\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}(2k-1)\right).$$
At first glance, this conveniently provides us with the denominator $sin(x/2)$ and the negative sign will disappear from the absolute value later. Now, to get the desired $b_k$, we look at the integers $2k+1$ and $2k-1$. Note that if we substitute $k+1$ into $2k-1$, we get
$$(2(k+1)-1)=2k+2-1=2k+1.$$
Thus, we can set
$$b_k=\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}(2k-1)\right)$$
and then, we can use the summation by parts formula
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+p} a_k sin(kx)
=-\frac{1}{2\sin(x/2)}
\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+p} a_k (b_{k+1} - b_k)
=-\frac{a_{n+p}b_{n+p+1}}{2\sin(x/2)}
+\frac{a_{m+1}b_{m+1}}{2\sin(x/2)}
+\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+p} \frac{b_k (a_{k} - a_{k-1})}{2\sin(x/2)}.$$
Utilizing the bounds on x, we can start analyzing the terms one by one, noting that sine and cosine are both bounded by one to achieve the desired bound.

Sources:

- I got the idea in the second equation from [here](https://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/08/06/prove-a-formula-for-the-sum-from-k1-to-n-of-sin-kx/).
- The formula for multiples of sines is [here](https://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/08/06/prove-a-formula-for-the-sum-from-k1-to-n-of-sin-kx/).